# How can I filter everything but prices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-cleaning

Below is an example of what I'm trying to clean, I want only the prices but without the $ in front of it because I am going to average the prices.

```
$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
$10.63 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:58:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
$9.69 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
$9.68 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
$11.21 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:00:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
$9.51 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:01:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

I am currently trying to use the below code to clean everything but what I want as said above it almost gives me what I want but, not close enough.

```
    // the example of what im trying to clean above is a string called data
    var data_array = Array.from(data)
    var data = data_array.join("")
    var data = data.split("$")
    var data = data.join("")
    var data = data.split("|")
    var data = data.join("")
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

```js
let data = '$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $10.63 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:58:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)$9.69 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $9.68 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)$11.21 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:00:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $9.51 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:01:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)'

let data_array = data.split("$").map(a => a.slice(0, a.indexOf('|')))
data_array.shift()
console.log(data_array)
```

Comment: A little explanation might help. What was wrong and how does your code help solve it?

Comment: Hey mate, you have a point, sorry but I'm not so good in explanations :( I don't even know is my answer what is asked for :(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is regex. Here, I am matching any non whitespace character between $ and |.

```js
const data = "$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $10.63 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:58:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $9.69 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $9.68 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $11.21 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:00:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) $9.51 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:01:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"

const prices = data.match(/(?<=\$)\S*(?=|)/gm);
console.log(prices)
```

##### Quick tutorial on Regex

Regex uses a `pattern` to match certain characters in a string.

Some basic concepts you should know are:

groups: `()`, A group of characters, or conditions, you want to match.

A simple usecase would be matching a word, such as `(title)`.

Groups also have a special feature where you can do checks before and after the group. These checks start with a question mark like `(?=title)`.

These checks are:

- `(?=)` positive look ahead
- `(?!)` negative look ahead
- `(?<=)` positive look behind
- `(?<!)` negative look behind

These checks are useful for what we want to do, which is match between two character, `$` and `|`.

Now, how would we use these checks?

For the example, we will use a part of your string.

`$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

Now, for this example, we will try and get the text in the brackets `Central Daylight Time`.

We want to make sure that our match has a bracket before and after it. Since we can't to check before, we want to be *positive* that the bracket is *behind*. So we will use **positive look behind** `(?<=)`.

And we want to check for a open bracket `(`, so we add it after. `(?<=\()`. We use `\` to escape the bracket, since it's a special character. You can see I also did so in the answer for `(?<=\$)`.

Now we need to make sure that the character after, is a closed bracket `)`.

We do the same, but this time we use a **positive look ahead** instead `(?=\))`.

Now we want to match all the word characters between them. So in between both groups we add the quantifiers. In this case `.+`

Now to teach you about quantifiers. Quantifiers tell you how many times to repeat the match. Here are the basic quantifiers.

- `*` 0 or more
- `?` 0 or 1
- `+` 1 or more
- `{n}` n times
- `{n, }` n or more times
- `{n, n2}` between n and n2

Out of these quantifiers, the most common ones you will use are `*` and `+`.

Now we will look at character groups.

- `\w` any word character.
- `\W` any non-word character.
- `\d` any digit.
- `\D` any non digit.

Then there is the wild card `.` that matches anything. We use it in the example, just because it's the cleanest, but if you look at my answer, I use `\S` that stand for *any non whitespace character*, which I used, so it wouldn't match the space after the price. There are many character groups, and you can google to find more.

Now we can add all the parts together, to get our Reg'ex pattern.

`(?<=\().+(?=\))`

Now I will wrap our pattern in `//` so we can add extra features. In this case, global - g, and multi-line - m. There are other settings you can use too, such as case-insensitive - i, but we don't need it for ours So now we have:

`/(?<=\().+(?=\))/gm`

Now we can try it in some JS.

```js
const data = "$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)";

const result = data.match(/(?<=\().+(?=\))/gm);
console.log(result);
```

Any more questions, ask in the comments, and I'll respond. Also, if you want to test your reg'ex, you can use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). It has a useful menu at the bottom right to read through the different features of Reg'ex.

Comment: this works but I would like to be able to look at it in the future for reference and be able to understand it since regex is just a bunch of special characters that i have no idea what they mean for the most part

Comment: I'll update it with a demo of regex, then. So you can understand it.

Comment: most people cant understand regex for the most part, i have been playing with javascript for close to 4 months and still dont understand it although i understand some components of it like the !

Comment: @Fisheiyy I updated my answer with a mini guide. Hopefully its useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

What you need is to split data into rows with splitting by a new line.
from there its easier to map over each row splitting it with separator '|' and splitting each price on two parts "$" and actual price, where yo pick the part you need which is numeric price representation.

```js
const data =
  `$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  $10.63 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:58:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  $9.69 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  $9.68 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  $11.21 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:00:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
  $9.51 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:01:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`;

const rows = data.split('\n');
const prices = rows.map(el => el.split(' | ')[0]).map(p => p.split('$')[1]).filter(e => e !== undefined);

console.log(prices);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is regex approach:

Regex: `(([$]\d{1,3}[$,\\.]?(\d{1,3})?))`

```js
const regex = /(([$]\d{1,3}[$,\\.]?(\d{1,3})?))/gm;

const str = `\$11.78 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:57:34 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
\$10.63 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:58:19 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
\$9.69 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:20 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
\$9.68 | Tue Sep 07 2021 14:59:35 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
\$11.21 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:00:36 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
\$9.51 | Tue Sep 07 2021 15:01:07 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`;

const prices = str.match(regex);

console.log(prices);
```